# redux-observable - await async actions and convert them to Promise using rootEpic

Tags: redux, promise, rxjs, redux-observable

Example in [next.js repository](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux-observable/pages/index.js) shows how we can convert root epic to Promise, so it's possible to `await` async action like `ajax`:

```
static async getInitialProps ({ store, isServer }) {
  const resultAction = await rootEpic(
    of(actions.fetchCharacter(isServer)),
    store
  ).toPromise() // we need to convert Observable to Promise
  store.dispatch(resultAction)

  return { isServer }
}
```

I wonder though how it would be possible to `await` more than one action. I managed to do it this way:

```
const actions = await Promise.all([
  rootEpic(of(fetchCharacterOne()), store).toPromise(),
  rootEpic(of(fetchCharacterTwo()), store).toPromise(),
  rootEpic(of(fetchCharacterThree()), store).toPromise(),
]);

actions.forEach(store.dispatch);
```

...but I wonder if there is a simpler way than calling `rootEpic` each time - I mean call it once with three actions to await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer accidentally in [universal-rxjs-ajax](https://github.com/mcmunder/universal-rxjs-ajax) docs. So that's the code I was looking for:

```
const initialData$ = of(
  fetchCharacterOne(),
  fetchCharacterTwo(),
  fetchCharacterThree(),
);

const actions = await rootEpic(initialData$, store)
  .pipe(toArray()) // buffers all emitted actions until Epic completes
  .toPromise();

actions.forEach(store.dispatch);
```