# NextJS: `HYDRATION` action doesn't receive server payload when using `redux-observable`

Tags: rxjs, next.js, redux-observable, next-redux-wrapper

Packages:

1. [`redux-observable`](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable)@2.0.0-rc.2
2. [`rxjs`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/) latest
3. [`universal-rxjs-ajax`](https://github.com/mcmunder/universal-rxjs-ajax) dev branch
4. [`next-redux-wrapper`](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) latest
5. `next.js` latest

I have a simple Page with `getStaticProps`:

```js
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps((store) => async (ctx) => {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_DATA' });
  // const response = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api');
  // const data = await response.json();

  // store.dispatch({ type: 'SERVER_ACTION', payload: data.characters });
  return {
    props: {},
  };
});
```

Action `'ADD_DATA'` triggers action `'SERVER_ACTION'`:

```js
export const AddDataEpic: Epic = (action$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('ADD_DATA'),
    mergeMap((action) =>
      request({ url: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api' }).pipe(
        map((response) => {
          return {
            type: 'SERVER_ACTION',
            payload: response.response.characters,
          };
        })
      )
    )
  );
```

Inside the `reducer` in the `case 'SERVER_ACTION':` clause I receive the payload:

```js
const server = (state: State = { data: null }, action: AnyAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HYDRATE: {
      console.log('HYDRATE >', action.payload); // logs out "HYDRATE > { server: { data: null } }"
      return {
        ...state,
        ...state.server,
        ...action.payload.server,
      };
    }

    case 'SERVER_ACTION': {
      console.log('SERVER_ACTION >', action.payload); // logs out "SERVER_ACTION > https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character"
      return {
        ...state,
        ...state.server,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But the payload isn't passed to `HYDRATE` action:
`console.log('HYDRATE >', action.payload); // logs out "HYDRATE > { server: { data: null } }"`

If I dispatch the `'SERVER_ACTION'` action from inside the `getStaticProps`:

```js
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps((store) => async (ctx) => {
  // store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_DATA' });
  const response = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api');
  const data = await response.json();

  store.dispatch({ type: 'SERVER_ACTION', payload: data.characters });
  return {
    props: {},
  };
});
```

The `HYDRATE` action inside the `reducer` receive the payload:
`HYDRATE > { server: { data: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character' } }`

I don't understand what's wrong with my code.
May it be a bug in one of the libraries? Or is it a mistake in my code?

If anyone has any suggestions, PLEASE

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this ?

Comment: I got a reply on my github issue: https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/376 they propose to follow the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950278/redux-observable-await-async-actions-and-convert-them-to-promise-using-rootepi but I haven't tried it myself

Answer (score 0):

@PYTHON DEVELOPER999 It might be due to the latest update on next-redux-wrapper, there are few migration steps =>

https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper#upgrade-from-6x-to-7x